# Getting list of users thta have access to Object Store account

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the following URL to list all SoftLayer Obhect Storage accounts.

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHubNetworkStorage.json?objectMask=mask[accountPassword,credentials,bytesUsed,permissionsGroupCount,permissionsGroups,propertyCount,properties,properties.type,properties.volume,storageType,totalBytesUsed]
```

How can I get the list of users granted access to each SoftLayer account?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look the following link:

- [Manage an Object Storage
  User](https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/manage-object-storage-user)

So, it means that an user who has these permissions:

1. **Manage Storage** (keyName: NAS_MANAGE)
2. **Manage CDN Account** (keyName: CDN_ACCOUNT_MANAGE)
3. **Manage CDN File Transfers** (keyName: CDN_FILE_MANAGE)

is able to view and interact with all Accounts and Clusters for Object Storage.

Just in case, if you want to see which users have these permissions, it's not possible to get a list from them, making a single call, but you can try the following call:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers?objectFilter={"users":{"userStatus":{"keyName":{"operation":"ACTIVE"}}}}&objectMask=mask[id,username,permissions]

Method: Get
```

then you need to check users (one by one), who have these permissions.

It can be easier, to get a list of users which have these permissions, using a programming language and filter the users through the permissions.

To see available programming languages supported by [SoftLayer](http://www.softlayer.com/):

- [SoftLayer Development Network](http://sldn.softlayer.com/)

If you need further assistance with any particular programming language, please let me know.